# Ignore null value while looping through an array

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, null

I'm building a method which prints certain specific values from my array. The thing is, each value from that array has multiple values given by a constructor so the array looks like this :

```
Constructor1[] tab1 = {new Constructor1 (var1: 1, var2: 3, var3: "Hi"),
                     null,
                     new Constructor1 (var1: 3, var2: 2, var3: "Ho"),
                     null}...
```

The null values correspond to empty instances of my constructor and I do not want to delete them. When I loop through my array I use a getter I built in another class to get the specific value.

```
for (int i = 0, i<= tab1.length, i++) {
    if (tab[i].getVar2() == 2){
    System.out.print(tab[i]);
    }
}
```

I can get the values to print right until I loop through null, which stops my program. The goal to my program is to extract certain things from the array and save them onto a file, but I cant extract everything I want because of null. For the purpose of this project I use FileReader, PrintReader etc...

Comment: `if (tab[i] != null) { ... }`

Comment: In Java before you call a method of object you must check the object is null or not null.Call null object's method will throw `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a null check

```
for (int i = 0, i<= tab1.length, i++) {
    if (tab[i]!=null &&tab[i].getVar2() == 2){
    System.out.print(tab[i]);
    }
}
```